# Android 4.4.2 x86 emulator wont start - stuck in a boot loop

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

I'm trying to launch a 4.4.2 API19 AVD, and this is all the gets printed in the ADB log, over and over:

```
    06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.4.2/KK/999428:eng/test-keys'
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 1694, tid: 1694, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ eax 00000000  ebx 0000069e  ecx 0000069e  edx 00000006
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ esi 0000069e  edi 00000002
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ eip b765cc96  ebp b76c1ce0  esp bfddbd90  flags 00000203
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 0003bc96  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 00000005  <unknown>
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd50  00000000
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd54  b6eb63de  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd58  b6eb8020  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd5c  b762eef9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_unlock+25)
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd60  000000b8
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd64  0000002e
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd68  b6eb542b  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so (mapFrameBufferLocked(private_module_t*)+11)
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd6c  b6eb7f98  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd70  00000000
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd74  fffffffe
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd78  b6eb8020  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd7c  b6eb5caa  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so (fb_device_open(hw_module_t const*, char const*, hw_device_t**)+186)
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd80  b6eb80e0  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd84  b772c66f  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd88  b762ed29  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+9)
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd8c  b76bcfcc  /system/lib/libc.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  bfddbd90  00000006
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd94  1f2156ba
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd98  b76bcfcc  /system/lib/libc.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbd9c  b7639436  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+102)
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbda0  0000069e
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbda4  0000069e
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbda8  00000006
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbdac  b6eb7f98  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbdb0  ffffffff
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbdb4  b6eb635d  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbdb8  b76393d9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+9)
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbdbc  b76bcfcc  /system/lib/libc.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbdc0  bfddbe0c  [stack]
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbdc4  b772c69f  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbdc8  b7ecc1c0  [heap]
06-19 16:07:11.071      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfddbdcc  b76397fc  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+44)
06-19 16:07:11.101      916-916/? I/ServiceManager﹕ service 'media.audio_flinger' died
06-19 16:07:11.101      916-916/? I/ServiceManager﹕ service 'media.player' died
06-19 16:07:11.101      916-916/? I/ServiceManager﹕ service 'media.camera' died
06-19 16:07:11.101      916-916/? I/ServiceManager﹕ service 'media.audio_policy' died
06-19 16:07:15.141    1731-1731/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger is starting
06-19 16:07:15.141    1731-1731/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
06-19 16:07:15.141    1731-1731/? D/libEGL﹕ Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
06-19 16:07:15.141    1731-1731/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
06-19 16:07:15.141    1731-1731/? D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-19 16:07:15.141    1731-1731/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ hwcomposer module not found
06-19 16:07:15.141    1731-1731/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
06-19 16:07:15.141    1731-1731/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000006c3 (code=-6), thread 1731 (surfaceflinger)
06-19 16:07:15.171    1730-1730/? I/Netd﹕ Netd 1.0 starting
06-19 16:07:15.171    1730-1730/? W/InterfaceController﹕ Warning (dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface command library
06-19 16:07:15.191    1732-1732/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
06-19 16:07:15.191    1732-1732/? W/linker﹕ libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
06-19 16:07:15.191    1732-1732/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is ON
06-19 16:07:15.211    1733-1733/? I/mediaserver﹕ ServiceManager: 0xb8588d40
06-19 16:07:15.211    1733-1733/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
06-19 16:07:15.211    1733-1733/? I/CameraService﹕ CameraService started (pid=1733)
06-19 16:07:15.211    1733-1733/? D/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient﹕ Emulated camera list:
06-19 16:07:15.211    1733-1733/? I/CameraService﹕ Loaded "Emulated Camera Module" camera module
06-19 16:07:15.211    1733-1733/? I/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ loadAudioPolicyConfig() loaded /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
06-19 16:07:15.211    1733-1733/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ loadHwModule() Loaded primary audio interface from Generic audio HW HAL (audio) handle 1
06-19 16:07:15.211    1733-1733/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ HAL output buffer size 1024 frames, normal mix buffer size 1024 frames
06-19 16:07:15.211    1733-1733/? I/AudioMixer﹕ found effect "Multichannel Downmix To Stereo" from The Android Open Source Project
06-19 16:07:15.211    1733-1733/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ Using module 1 has the primary audio interface
06-19 16:07:15.211    1732-1732/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-19 16:07:15.211    1732-1732/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-19 16:07:15.221    1732-1732/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-19 16:07:15.221    1732-1732/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-19 16:07:15.221    1732-1732/? D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
06-19 16:07:15.221    1733-1743/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ AudioFlinger's thread 0xb6079010 ready to run
06-19 16:07:15.221    1733-1743/? W/AudioFlinger﹕ Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
06-19 16:07:15.221    1733-1743/? W/AudioFlinger﹕ Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
06-19 16:07:15.221    1733-1743/? W/AudioFlinger﹕ Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
06-19 16:07:15.221    1733-1743/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ no wake lock to update!
06-19 16:07:15.221    1733-1733/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
06-19 16:07:15.221    1733-1733/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ loadHwModule() error -2 loading module r_submix
06-19 16:07:15.221    1733-1733/? W/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ could not open HW module r_submix
06-19 16:07:15.221    1733-1733/? I/AudioPolicyService﹕ Loaded audio policy from LEGACY Audio Policy HAL (audio_policy)
06-19 16:07:15.221    1732-1732/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
06-19 16:07:15.271      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-19 16:07:15.271      920-920/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.4.2/KK/999428:eng/test-keys'
```

I am on 64 bit Debian Linux.  I have other 4.4.2 AVDs running, so it maybe something to do with the hardware device profile I'm using?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue.

thanks to another post on so which i can not find anymore i used this method :

On windows 7 (perhaps on MAC too ?) :
simply delete the .android folder in your USER/ folder and voilà.

When you open eclipse or android studio, the .android folder will be recreated and your avd will run just fine.

PS : you do not need to uninstall the android sdk manager program.

Comment: This folder contains all configuration files for the AVDs, deleting it is not a good idea... Unless you know what you are doing and do not care about losing all your configured AVDs (among others !)

Comment: of course the above steps will erase all your avd configs, but it does not take long to recreate them and at least your avds will work again (hopefully). It is faster than uninstalling java sdk and bla bla bla.